# DataHandler, trying to write its content into a file

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, datahandler

I am having a `DataHandler` problem.

I am trying to collect their contents in a file. This is created with the size of the buffer allocated damaged but without content, so I do not get to write anything on it.

This is the code i'm using:
Important, the "ciDoc" is a `javax.activation.DataHandler`.

```
byte[] buffer = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(ciDoc.getInputStream());

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(fileItemUCM.getFile(), buffer);

item.setFile(fileItemUCM.getFile());
```

The `fileItemUCM.getFile()` is always damaged, really is nothing writing into it.

Comment: You should post your code, as is it's hard to tell what you are talking about

Comment: You should add more details, this explains not much.

Comment: Please update your question  and introduce the code, do not put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue. The trouble happened because in the server side someone enables the MTOM way to tranfer information. So modifing spring webservicestemplates for working with MTOM resolve my problem.

thanks,